# How to determine an absolute-positioned element's container

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom control that needs to render a pop-up window directly below its "main" control body (a DIV element). The problem I'm running into is how to set the pop-up coordinate location if the control has no "knowledge" of the its container settings.

For example, take this section of code:

```
// library call to extract document-based coordinates (returns object with X and Y fields) of the "controlBodyElement" (a DIV)
var pt = some.library.getDocumentPosition(controlBodyElement)
// frame (the "popup") is a DIV pointer 
frame.style.position = "absolute"
frame.style.top = pt.y + controlBodyElement.clientHeight + 1 + "px"  // Line "A"
// frame.style.top = "0px"   // Line "B" -- finds the relativity point of absolute-position
```

Line "A" - causes the popup to be rendered way below the controlBodyElement
Line "B" - renders the popup way above the controlBodyElement.

Q: what element setting/attribute should be searched for in the DOM tree to determine which element some absolute-positioned child is being anchored relative to?

UPDATE: I think if someone can explain to me what page mechanics would cause an absolute-positioned element (using top = 0px) to be rendered halfway down the page (instead of the top) then I can write the logic to sort things out; I'm just not sure I need to be looking for...

Comment: If you use jQuery you can use the offset method to know the parent's top and left properties and position the child element relative to those values
http://api.jquery.com/offset/ 

I'm not giving you this as a answer cause you're not using jQuery

Comment: I'm not sure how the JQ library does this, but our position extract uses self-recursion to accumulate the offsetLeft and offsetRight properties of the "element.offsetParent(s)" lineage. (I'm guessing it does something similar?) For some reason the values derived from the method aren't positioning the popup in the correct location. I'm wondering if I need to write a similar recursion process to determine the Positioning stack of a given element...?

Comment: What you need is the elment's *[containing block](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Containing_blocks)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Pumbaa80 for the information - that was exactly what I was trying to figure out.

In case it'll help someone else later, here is a revamped locator method that will extract that particular offset coordinates (as opposed to a logical screen location)...

```
// relative location from nearest Positioned ancestor
getPositionedOffset = function(element, coordinates) {
  // create a coordinates object if one was not assigned (first iteration)
  if(coordinates == undefined) { 
    coordinates = {x: 0, y: 0 }
  }

  if (element.offsetParent) {
    switch(window.getComputedStyle(element).position) {
      case "relative":
      case "absolute":
      case "fixed":
        return coordinates
      default:
        coordinates.x += element.offsetLeft
        coordinates.y += element.offsetTop
        getPositionedOffset(element.offsetParent, coordinates) // step into offsetParent
    }
  }
  return coordinates
}
```

NOTE: code is functional in Chrome; minor tweaking will be needed for operation in some of the other browser flavors.

EDIT:

In most cases the function will be called with a single argument (that being an element reference), like so:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("foo")
var relativeLoc = getPositionedOffset(ele)
```

However, if a manual shift needs to be factored in (for example +5px right, and -10px up) then include the second argument:

```
var relativeLocWithOffset = getPositionedOffset(ele, {x:5, y:-10})
```